# how fputc affect file size?

Tags: c++, c, filesize

I am using fputc (in C/C++) to output some data into a file, and the file size matters to me in my project. But the size of resutling file seems incorrect, a simple code example:

```
FILE *fp = fopen( "123.txt", "w" );
for( int i=0; i<64; i++ )
    fputc( i, fp );
fclose( fp );
```

After excuting this code, the file's size is 65B, not 64B, but if I use `fputc(1,fp)`, the file size is 64B.
Is there any trick? or anything I can do to control the size of output file?

Comment: _'how fputc affect file size?'_ bytewise?!? ....

Comment: Can you show exact bytes from your 123.txt? Dump it with `hexdump -C` (linux)

Comment: It's possible when you output byte value `13` (CR) it is getting translated to CRLF because you `fopen`ed the file in text vs binary mode.  Change your mode to `wb` and retry.

Comment: Or LF gets translated to CRLF. Same result though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd guess you're doing this on Windows.

Since you opened the file in translated (text) mode, new-lines are converted to a carriage-return/line-feed pairs. The character code 10 happens to be treated as a new-line, so you end up with an extra byte compared to what you wrote.

If you open the file in binary mode instead, this won't happen.

```
FILE *fp = fopen( "123.txt", "wb" );
```

Note the `b` added to the open mode-string.